# Is there a hadith about the recitation of surah al-ala in Jumu'ah salah?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, reference-request, surat-al-ala

I have observed in the last few months that during the Jumu'ah salah, I hear the imam recite surah al-ala quite frequently, nearly all of the time. The previous imam also did this. I wondered why this is, and I presume that this is based on ahadith?

**Question:** Is there a hadith about the recitation of surah al-ala in Jumu'ah salah?

<sub>If there is, please could you include details regarding the authenticity and chain of narration.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jummah prayers, it is mustahab to recite:

- Al-Jummah and Al-Munafiqun or
- Al-A'la and Al-Ghashiyah

This is based on the narrations below:

> #### عن ابن أبي رافع، قال: استخلف مروان أبا هريرة على المدينة، وخرج إلى مكة، فصلى لنا أبو هريرة الجمعة، فقرأ بعد سورة الجمعة، في الركعة الآخرة: إذا جاءك المنافقون، قال: فأدركت أبا هريرة حين انصرف، فقلت له: إنك قرأت بسورتين كان علي بن أبي طالب يقرأ بهما بالكوفة، فقال أبو هريرة: إني سمعت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، يقرأ بهما يوم الجمعة
>
> Ibn Abi Rafi' said: Marwan appointed Abu Hurairah in charge of Al-Madinah, and went out to Makkah. Abu Hurairah led us in prayer on Friday, and after Surat Al-Jumu'ah he recited:
>   "When the hypocrites come to you" in the second Rak'ah. I caught up with Abu Hurairah when he left and said to him: "You recited two Surah which 'Ali bin Abi Talib
>   used to recite in Al-Kufah." Abu Hurairah said: "I heard the Messenger of Allah ﷺ reciting them on Fridays"
>
> #### عن النعمان بن بشير، قال: كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يقرأ في العيدين، وفي الجمعة بسبح اسم ربك الأعلى، وهل أتاك حديث الغاشية
>
> An-Nu'man bin Bashir said: For the Two 'Ids and for Jumu'ah, the Messenger of Allah ﷺ used to recite: "Glorify the Name of your Lord, the Most High" and: "Has there come to you the narration of the overwhelming?"
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim , كتاب الجمعة  , باب ما يقرأ في صلاة الجمعة](https://sunnah.com/muslim/7/76-80)</sup>